# removing 12th character of the first column from txt file in mac terminal

Tags: string, terminal

I have 200 large txt files, each is made up of 150 columns. I would like to remove the 12th character of the first column using terminal in mac. Is there a fast way to do that?

Column 1 looks like this

20101553782**0**10002019

I would like to look like this

2010155378210002019

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
sed -i 's/.//12' file
```

Where `file` is the path to your file.